# linux-pyserial :could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0 No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, pyserial

could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyAMA0'

I am using cp2102 usb to uart bridge which is installed on linux kernel 3.x.x

```
>>> import serial
>>> port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)
```

it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyAMA0'
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and it came out to be an installation problem.What I did , was to use /dev/ttyS0 (which is the serial COM port) and minicom to make sure that pyserial was installed properly.

Comment: yes That would probably happen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was logging in  /dev/
and seeing what's listed there and probably u'll find a directory called serial
The code for this

```
ls /dev/serial/by-id/
```

and replace the name of the device by ttyAM0
for me it become

```
 serial.Serial("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001-if00-port0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)
```